# Python requests, just confirm status code and not download body

Tags: python, python-requests

I am looking at doing "proof of life" test for some sites my team is developing by just doing status code confirmation and do not actually need the document body.  From what the Python Requests documentation says **stream** is **False** by default and the headers AND body are pulled down.  However by setting **stream** to **True** only the headers are grabbed.  My concern is the possibility of false positives.

I am trying something like the following:

```
    url = random.choice(app.conf['TEST_SITES'])
    ua = random.choice(app.conf['USER_AGENTS'])
    proxies = {
               'https':'{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(proxy_user, proxy_pass, proxy_ip, proxy_port),
               'https':'{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(proxy_user, proxy_pass, proxy_ip, proxy_port)
              }
    headers = {'user-agent': ua}
    proxy_session = requests.Session()
    proxy_session.max_redirects = app.conf['MAX_REDIRECTS']
    response = requests.get(headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True, timeout=5)
    ret_code = response.status_code
    response.close
    # Do stuff based on status code #
```

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question?